# Laravel Route Parameter

Tags: laravel, methods, routes, controller, content-management-system

I want to go pages which is in database. So I am trying to use parameter in route page.

Route is that.

```
$page = Pages::get();
 foreach($page as $key){
   $id= $key->id;
 Route::get($key->pages_name,'ThemeRestorantController@pages($id)');
}
```

pages method is that in ThemeRestorantController

```
public function pages($id)
{
   dd($id);
}
```

I'm taking follow error.
BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 283: Method [pages($id)] does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

At first welcome to SO :)

you cant send parameter inside `()` in method controller you should send your parameter in URL like below:

```php
Route::get($key->pages_name . '/{id}','ThemeRestorantController@pages');
```

Answer (score 0):

your route definition is wrong. you have to pass the parameter in the url part, not in the controller method.

```
Route::get($key->pages_name/{id}, 'ThemeRestorantController@pages');
```

and you don't need to loop to make your route. you can simply use the slug as parameter along with id

```
Route::get('{id}/{pages_name}', 'ThemeRestorantController@pages')->name('page-route');
//it's better to use a named route
```

then you can use it controller like

```
public function pages($id, $pages_name)
{
    $page = Pages::find($id);
    return view('view_file', compact('page'));
}
```

and calling the page from a view like

```
<a href="{{ route('page-route', [$page->id, $page->page_name]) }}">My Page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

as per your code that is not the right way to loop on `web.php` so better way would be catch all and handel in controller

#### web.php

```php
Route::get('{pages_name}','ThemeRestorantController@pages');
```

#### ThemeRestorantController.php

```php
public function pages($pages_name)
{
    $page = Pages::where('page_name',$pages_name)->firstOrFail();
    return view($pages_name,compact('page'));
}
```

in this way `pages_name` view load and `$page`  data will be send to that view